# Can't delete a row from a DataGridView in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I wanted to delete a row from a DataGridView by simply pressing the 'Delete' key like I always do but weirdly it wasn't working.
I have then done some tests in my form and figured it out that it might be due having the *RowHeadersVisible* property set to false.

> **My DataGridView looks like this -**

[image: DataGridView]

Is it possible to delete a row with *RowHeadersVisible* property set to false? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The `RowHeadersVisible` itself doesn't prevent you from deleting a row. If the `AllowUserToDeleteRows` property is set to true, you should be able to delete a row (as long as the whole row is selected). Now, if `RowHeadersVisible` is false, you can't click the row header to select the whole row anymore. In this case, you need to make sure that the `SelectionMode` property is set to `FullRowSelect`.

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed That's it! My `SelectionMode` was set to `RowHeaderSelect`. Changed to `FullRowSelect` and it works! Thanks mate!

Comment: Note that my first comment wasn't accurate. `RowHeadersVisible` does have an effect on this (not directly though) as explained above.

Comment: That's right. I was able to delete the row with `RowHeadersVisible` set to true but always had to select the full row like you explained. I should've seen that but was focused on the wrong problem! Well you helped me a lot. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @AhmedAbdelhameed commented in the comment section the problem was not directly in the property `RowHeadersVisible` being set to false. It is stil possible to delete a row by pressing the 'Delete' key just by setting the property `SelectionMode` to `FullRowSelect`.